# How to change some of my code to a Class?

Tags: c#, class, methods

I wrote some code and it works, but now trying to take some of my code and change it to a Class. I already change part of the code to first a method and then turn it into a Class. But this last part of code having trouble figuring out how to change to a method so then I can make a Class.

```
else if (input == "3")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Here are your Students: ");
    Array.Sort(names);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", names));                    
    Console.WriteLine("");

    double average = gradesList.Average();

    if (average >= 90)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There average is a {average.ToString("n2")} which is an A.");

    }
    else if (average >= 80)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There average is a {average.ToString("n2")} which is an B.");
    }
    else if (average >= 70)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There average is a {average.ToString("n2")} which is an C.");
    }
    else if (average >= 60)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There average is a {average.ToString("n2")} which is an D.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There average is a {average.ToString("n2")} which is an E.");
    }

}
```

The first part I was thinking of leaving that and just change the Grade part into a Class. I tried public static string GetLetterGrade(int average)
 return ($"There average is a {average.ToString("n2")} which is an A.") but get all kinds or errors that I  don't understand.

Comment: or I was thinking of making two method- Class one for listing names and then one for grades.

Comment: while got the Grade part working so now I guess I will work on "Here are your Students part to turn into a Class".

Answer (score 1):

I would make the grade a non-mutable struct. It represents a value and should be a value type. A class is a reference type.

```
public readonly struct Grade
{
    public Grade(double percentage)
    {
        Percentage = percentage;
    }

    public double Percentage { get; }

    public char Letter
    {
        get {
            if (Percentage >= 90) return 'A';
            if (Percentage >= 80) return 'B';
            if (Percentage >= 70) return 'C';
            if (Percentage >= 60) return 'D';
            return 'E';
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{Percentage:n2} ({Letter})";
}
```

Since the if-statements return, it is not necessary to have an else-part.

Then you can easily print the message with

```
double average = gradesList.Average();
var grade = new Grade(average);
Console.WriteLine(
    $"There average is a {grade.Percentage:n2} which is an {grade.Letter}.");
```

Note that because `ToString` is overridden, you can print the grade directly.

```
Console.WriteLine($"The average grade is {grade}");
```

It will print something like `The average grade is 74.25 (C)`.

Comment: This is what I did.  Console.WriteLine("There average was " + average);
                        Console.WriteLine("Whis is a " + StandardMessages.GetGrade(average));

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
public static char GetLetterGrade(double average)
{
    if (average >= 90)
    {
        return 'A';
    }
    else if (average >= 80)
    {
        return 'B';
    }
    else if (average >= 70)
    {
        return 'C';
    }
    else if (average >= 60)
    {
        return 'D';
    }
    return 'E';
}
```

but if you wish to use `GetLetterGrade(int average)` overload, use it like this

```
double average = gradesList.Average();
var grade = GetLetterGrade((int)average);
```

Comment: That's works, I had something like that but where I was messing up was the way I was calling it from my main. But I do it working now just need to add output thanks.

Comment: It's not displaying the grade but the average. This is what I have in main.

Comment: double average = gradesList.Average();
                    {
                        StandardMessages.GetGrade(average);
                        Console.WriteLine(average);
                    }

Comment: I need to change some var names both are using average.

Comment: ```double average = gradesList.Average(); Console.WriteLine(StandardMessages.GetGrade(average));```
or assign `StandardMessages.GetGrade(average)` to variable and print that variable: ```var gradeLetter = StandardMessages.GetGrade(average); Console.WriteLine(gradeLetter);```

Comment: Still having trouble first the average is coming out wrong but grade is right. I input 10 and 20 and give me average of 69 and letter grade of E.

Comment: [Debug your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio?tabs=csharp) and inspect the variables, including the list items.

Comment: well got the Grade part working so now I guess I will work on "Here are your Students part to turn into a Class". Thanks for the help. My var problem I was calling them wrong. I need to call it grade like StandardMessages.GetGrade(average) and for average just call average.